# Weekly scheduler / timer user interface on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We would like to implement an interactive weekly scheduler.  We are using Highcharts extensively on the rest of our project and was hoping to use Highcharts for this purpose rather than create our own custom built interface.

Attached is a picture of the intended user interface.  The idea is that a user with editing rights will be able to click and drag anywhere in the pane to turn the scheduled block on or off, depending on the current state of the block.  We would like to use 5 minute intervals (ie 288 slots per day).

Is there any way in which Highcharts will be able to support this functionality?

[image: SchedulerImage]

Comment: I have made very simple example how you can make your scheduler. Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hd6q8v48/1/

Comment: Yea, i was thinking heatmap would be the way to go as well.

Comment: Thank you, we will try the heatmap - seems like a feasible answer.